# A geometric interpretation of the conditional Variance

Tags: probability-theory

We know that we can see conditional expectation as a projection. To be more specific, let be $<X,Y> = E[XY]$ the usual inner product in $L^{2}$. We know that:

$$E(Y|X) = \hbox{argmin}_{Z \in \mathcal{F}} E[(Y - Z)^2]$$

or

$$E(Y|X) = \hbox{argmin}_{Z \in \mathcal{F}} ||Y - Z||^2$$

where $\mathcal{F}$ is simply the sigma algebra generated by $X$, i.e., $\mathcal{F} = \sigma(X)$. I would like to know if there is any geometric interpretation for the conditional variance $V(Y|X)$.

I do not know I'm right in the following reasoning: if $U:= Y -E(Y|X) $, then $V(Y|X)= E(U^2|X)$. In this way, we can say that $V(Y|X)$ is the projection of the random variable $U^2$ in $\mathcal{F}$. However, if my reasoning is right, I am not satisfied. Perhaps there is another interpretation more interesting.

Comment: Exact ; congratulations for having found this result by yourself ! This result is fantastic in itself ; what who you like "more interesting" ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I can not tell you exactly. I get other results that I find interesting. For example, to show that $E (Y | X)$ is the projection, we have to show that $<U, Z> = 0$ for all $Z \in \mathcal{F}$, i.e., $E(U) = 0$, because $1 \in \mathcal{F}$. This is quite geometric. In fact, what led me to the question is the suspicion that the famous formula $V (X) = E (V (Y | X))+ V (E (Y | X))$ is the  econometric(?) version of the pythagoras's theorem,  taking into account that $V (X) = || X ||^2$.

Comment: Connected : https://mathoverflow.net/q/16471, http://webhost.hec.fr/rosu/research/notes/conditionalprob.pdf

Comment: @JeanMarie it's fantastic. Thanks too much.

Comment: @JeanMarie I have doubt about the mathoverflow link. I know that $X$ and $Y$, with joint distribution $g(x,y)$, are independent if $g_{X|Y}(x|y) = g_X(x)$. How can I show that this definition is equivalent to $\mathbb{E}[f(X)|Y]=\mathbb{E}f(X)$ for every reasonable function $f$?

Comment: Sorry, I think this is not so difficult. Maybe it's just a matter of integrating. Right? $E[f(X)|Y = y] = \int f(x) g_{X|Y}(x|y)dx =\int f(x) g_X(x) dx = E[f(X)]$.

Comment: It is possible that I can not demonstrate the reciprocal.